# Low quality posts - "come back in" information ... changes all the time?

Tags: discussion, review

I am doing lqp reviews daily these days.

Some days I start early; do 20 reviews maybe 7 AM. I am told: come back in 12 hours. I look into the queue again in the evening; and yep; it works; I can do another 20; and then I am told: you did 40 reviews today; and you have to wait some X hours.

But lately, things seem to be much "stricter"; as I really can do only 20 votes per day; and no way around that.

But I am very much convinced that I had days with **less** than 20 hours between my review sessions. Thus wondering: has there been changes to the implementation lately; or are there other explanations regarding my observations?

Comment: How many review audits have you failed in the last 30 days?

Comment: Some ;-) ... but those "changing numbers" is something I experienced over the last 10 days or so. So there haven't been fails since then. Well; there was one on Sunday ... but on a different review queue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The availability of review tasks is based on the UTC day. Once you have maxed out, you have to wait for 0 UTC to be able to review in that queue again*. The interface expresses this in relative time: come back in X hours (or minutes if under an hour). Here X depends on when you reached the review limit, which naturally varies depending on how quick you are and when you started.

If you remember what 0 UTC is in your timezone, you'll know exactly when you can review again.

(*) Exception: the review limit is increased when the queue size is large enough. So it's possible that after you reached the limit of 20, the queue grows again and you can review until the increased limit of, say, 40. (Details are site-specific)

Comment: hint: UTC time is shown at the top of the achievements notification bar (where rep point increases are shown in green also), so no need to "remember" what 0 UTC is ...